# VSTS Variable Group API for updating a variable?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

Is there a API call (maybe a PUT) available to update variables in a variable group?

I tried a PUT to

```
https://<my>.visualstudio.com/<project>/_apis/distributedtask/variablegroups
```

with JSON like

```
{"variables": {"somevariable":{"value":"12"}}}
```

But I get an error

```
The requested resource does not support http method 'PUT'.
```

Thanks

Comment: You could change a variable via ##vso[task.setvariable variable=sauce]crushed tomatoes
##vso[task.setvariable variable=secretSauce;issecret=true]crushed tomatoes with garlic Ref https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/definitions/build/variables?view=vsts&tabs=batch. Does it do what you want to achieve?

Comment: @RodrigoWerlang Thanks. I tried this but could not get it to work via the powershell build task, after creating a variable in the variable tab with the value "12', the script does 

    Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=TestVariable]test"

    Write-Host Test:$(TestVariable)

The result is:

    Test:12
 
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just remove Write-Host. I always use it like "##vso[task.setvariable variable=TestVariable]test" and then you can test it with Write-Output "test: $(TestVariable)". There is no need to create the variable at the variables tab. You could, but you don't need it. Please let me know if it works

Comment: I gave it a go like this "##vso[task.setvariable variable=TestVariable]test" and then Write-Output "test: $(TestVariable)". However I get this message as output: TestVariable : The term 'TestVariable' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable 
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\vso-agent-v2\_work\_temp\2b8d85c6-7d05-4232-ae3f-baa7b866b6ff.ps1:49 char:23
+ Write-Output "test: $(TestVariable)"

Comment: I'm sorry @gilweb. I wrote it wrong. The vso part is correct. But the write-output not. The correct would be use it in you build subsequent build tasks as a variable like $(TestVariable). Please let me know

Comment: @RodrigoWerlang Bingo! Yes this works and it did help me. You can't use this method to update Variable Group variables that I can see (see the Library tab in VSTS build) so it doesn't answer my question specifically, but it did help me in that when you use a powershell task to make API calls to update variable group values as the accepted solution does, the updated values are not available in the current build. Your way gave me a solution to that issue. Thanks!

Comment: See my answer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/57697611/467851 for a way of doing that via Azure CLI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Variable group can be updated by [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/distributedtask/variablegroups/update). Details as below:

```
PUT https://account.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/{project}/_apis/distributedtask/variablegroups/{variableGroupId}?api-version=4.1-preview
```

application/json

```
{
  "variables": {
    "var1": {
      "value": "new value"
    },
    "var2": {
      "value": "new value"
    }
  },
  "type": "Vsts",
  "name": "variable group name",
  "description": "Updated variable group"
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thanks! Do you happen to know what security scope is needed to execute these API calls? I tried it with a token that has Build(read and execute) but that gave me a 401.

Comment: You can user personal access token with full scopes.

Comment: Thanks. For security reasons, though, I'd rather not use full scope. Can we be more specific?

Comment: No, it needs full scopes PAT. Even you deselect any item from the scopes, you will get 401 error.

Comment: It doesn't support if you want to update just 1 variable among many.

Comment: @MarinaLiu how to get the variableGroupId, I can not see the on my set - i just have the variableGroup name only.. would you help me on this.

Comment: I got it, from this link - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/variable-groups?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#list-variable-groups

Answer (score 0):

After much trial and error with this I found an excellent tutorial here - This worked for me:

[Updating a VSTS variable group from the command line](https://www.danielstocker.net/updating-a-vsts-variable-group-from-the-command-line/)

Thanks Daniel Stocker!