# Azure DevOps: How to set the value of the Variable in Variable Group

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am trying to overwrite the value of the variable from **Variable Group** in Azure DevOps and it's not working.  It's always showing the original value.

I wrote my Powershell scripts as shown by these links:

- [Microsoft](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/559588/how-to-override-variable-group-variables-through-p.html)
- [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52399076/how-to-increase-update-variable-group-value-using-azure-devops-build-definition)

I added the Variable Group and Link it in my Build pipeline.

[image]

I wrote the following scripts in **Power Shell Script** task.

```
Write-Host "Original BPOwner = $(BPOwner)"

Write-Host "Changing value of BPOwner to Bright Ran"
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=BPOwner;]Bright Ran"

Write-Host "New BPOwner = $(BPOwner)"
```

However, in the Build, it's always showing the original value and it's never changed to the value I want to set.

[image]

Could you please suggest me how I could set this value in the Build Pipeline?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The new value available only in the next tasks, not in the same task when you change the value. for example, I added another PS task with `Write-Host "New BPOwner = $(BPOwner)"`:

[image]

The above it's the behavior of the logging command `##vso[task.setvariable variable]` and not only to the variable group.

Comment: Yes, if I add another Task and write the new value, it works as expected.  Actually, I am trying to set the value in Build Pipeline and re-use it in Release in AzureDevOps.   In Release task, it's always set to original value and never updated.  Could you pls help?

Comment: Do you want to change the value in the build and in the release get the new value?

Comment: yes, correct.  I want to get that dynamic value and re-use that new value in Release

Comment: @TTCG you can do it with rest API, see my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56558143/is-there-a-way-to-set-variables-in-variable-groups/56558502#56558502