# How to use a custom variable from build-pipeline in a release pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

**Question:**
Is there any way to define a custom-variable in a build pipeline in azure-devops, which then can be used in/exposed to the release pipeline in any way?

**Scenario:**
We are not using a variable group, because we need to dynamically set the variable in the build pipeline and then consume it in the release pipeline - it is not a static super global.

Checked the docs at [release variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=batch#debug-mode) and  [build variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch) but could not find any helping information or a hint, that this is possible.

**What I tried**

1. Define a `variable` in `variables` ( in the build pipeline ) and try to access it in the release pipeline using `$(name)` or checking if it is in `env`.

**Extras - Motivation**
The motivation behind this is

1. read the latest git-tag used in a build-pipeline step and expose this into the pipeline variable `VERSION` ( actually, we bump patch during that )
2. Releasing builds is a manual step.
3. If a build is released, the azure-devops gui shows us all the variables of the release-pipeline, which are "settable during release - this includes the version we want to release this package with
4. we want this "VERSION" to be prefilled with the version of the build-pipeline as a suggestion for the next version
5. In the release pipeline we checkout the repo, add the `VERSION` as a tag and package/publish the artifact with this version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to use a custom variable from build-pipeline in a release pipeline

You could try to use the REST API [Release Definitions - Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/definitions/update?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) to update the default variable in the release pipeline to use the value defined in a build pipeline.

```
PUT https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/release/definitions?api-version=5.1
```

Details:

Define a custom-variable in a **build pipeline,** like `TestValue`, the value is `123`:

[image]

Also define the same custom-variable in a **Release pipeline** with **default** value `123`:

[image]

Then add a inline powershell scripts to invoke the REST API `Definitions - Update` to update the default value in the release pipeline:

```
$url = "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/<OrganizationName>/<ProjectName>/_apis/release/definitions/<DefinitionId>?api-version=5.1"

Write-Host "URL: $url"
$pipeline = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Get -Headers @{
    Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"
}
Write-Host "Pipeline = $($pipeline | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100)"

# Update an existing variable named TestValue to its new value 987
$pipeline.variables.TestValue.value = "$(TestValue)"

####****************** update the modified object **************************
$json = @($pipeline) | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 99


Write-Host "URL: $json "

$updatedef = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Put -Body $json -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"}

write-host "==========================================================" 
Write-host "The value of Varialbe 'TestValue' is updated to" $updatedef.variables.TestValue.value
```

In this case, we could dynamically set the variable when we queue the build pipeline, and this value will overwrite the default value in the release pipeline, so that we could use it release pipeline.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That sounds very promising - just a question for the general understanding. Setting TestValue this way - does this basically mean for 'the next release pipeline instantiation' - no matter for which build, right?it will basically change the global definition of the release pipeline variable (forever and for all future builds). Is that the right understanding in this case?

Comment: Even though this approach can have side effects since it does not respect the availability of several builds which might be releaydable at the same the same time (with possibly different version context), I would expect this to be practical still, since the most recent build will set the most recent version+1, which would be correct even if we release.an older.job, which saved an 'older version' during it's build time. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This is impossible by default, but you can use 2 extensions from the marketplace:

1) [Shared variable updater](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Lanalua.lanalua-variableupdater) - Create a variable group and during the build update there the variables dynamically with this task. you can also do it with your script, see the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56558143/is-there-a-way-to-set-variables-in-variable-groups/56558502#56558502).

2) [Variable Kit for Azure DevOps Services](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MatiasBorgeaud.azurevarkit) - During a Build, save variables to a json file stored along with your build assets. During a Release, load the saved variables and use them within the release definition.

Comment: It seems like both cases are problatic, AFAIU. 1) is problematic if you have buildRun1, then buildRun2, and then release buildRun1 - the variable would have the value of buildRun2 since variable groups are super-globals and not "pipeline run" scoped, right

Comment: 2) is problematic since we need the variable to expand a pipeline-variable in the release step, which has the flag set "settable during release step" - we basically "prefill" the variable from the build, but we need it to be "changeable" in this UI later. This means, it is "pre first task in the release pipeline" and we could not really read the json file. Are there any other ways? Hint: i updated my motivation in the question so you might understand what we actually try to do

Comment: 1) You are right, but also if set a regular build variable will be available in the release you still have this problem, not?

Comment: I though pipeline variables are instance variables, valid for this "run" of the pipeline, and expected that "instance" to be carried over to the actual release pipeline. Beside that, is it actually possible to set a "release pipeline variable" using a variable group, like setting the value to `$(mygroup.var)`?