# How to pass Variable value between two yaml pipeline in azure

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

I have two pipelines one is primary which triggers the other. How to pass a variable set on the first pipeline to second triggered one.

Example:
Variable-Name: Validate = True

I want to pass the validate variable to secondary triggered pipeline . I could not find any documentation that would help.

Comment: This can be useful for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62357787/share-variables-across-build-pipelines-in-azure-devops

Comment: Do you have questions related to this ticket?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could store the necessary value to a file, then include this file in current build's artifact (Publish pipeline artifact task).

Then in secondly pipeline, you could add [Download Pipeline Artifacts task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/download-pipeline-artifact?view=azure-devops) to download latest artifact of first build and read the content of necessary file.

If you are using pipeline resource (could enable trigger), please add [Download task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/resources?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema#download-for-pipelines) to download artifact of that pipeline resource.

[Resources: pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/resources?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema#resources-pipelines)