# Create variable in Azure pipeline to use in a different pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

We have separate pipelines for our infrastructure and our application deployments. For our infrastructure, we are using terraform and i know that you can use terraform outputs as variables in later tasks within the same pipeline but is it possible to save the output as a variable in azure so that it can be used in a different pipeline.

We are looking to use this for S3 bucket names to use in the application code and for VPC subnet and SG ids in serverless.

Is this possible to save variables in the pipeline?

Answer (score 2):

There is a [variable group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/variable-groups?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) in Azure DevOps to share **static values** across pipelines.

In your case, if you want to save the terraform output as a variable in the variable group, you need to do something e.g. [call the REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52399076/how-to-increase-update-variable-group-value-using-azure-devops-build-definition) dynamically to set the variable in the variable group, then you can use it in another pipeline.

You could also refer to this [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62357787/share-variables-across-build-pipelines-in-azure-devops).