# How to get variable values from pipeline resources in azure pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-yaml

Basically, I have 2 Individual Azure Pipelines (CI, CD). And, I have enabled trigger only for the CI pipeline. Once the CI (build) pipeline was completed, it should trigger the CD pipeline. And, I am passing the parameters and variables in the CI pipeline. But, I want to utilize the same CI parameter values in the CD pipeline also.

```
### CI Pipeline ###
parameters:
- name: environment
  displayName: 'Choose Environment'
  type: string
  default: Dev
  values:
    - Dev
    - Qa
    - Stage
    - Demo
    - Live

variables:
- group: PoC-Web
- group: PoC-Secrets
- name: version
```

In the CI Pipeline, am using the environment parameter and declaring the version variable. Now, I want to Utilize these values in the CD Pipeline.

```
### CD Pipeline ###
resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: web-ci
    source: PoC-Web-CI
    trigger:
     branches: 
      include:
        - cicd/azure-pipelines
        - develop
stages:
- stage: 'Package_Deploy'
  jobs:
  - deployment: 'Deploy_to_Server'
    environment: 'PoC-Web.PoC_WEB_SERVER'
    strategy:
      rolling:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - task: CmdLine@2
            inputs:
              script: |              
                echo "Fetching CI Pipeline Environment Variables"
                echo "Pipeline-ID: $(resources.pipeline.web-ci.pipelineID)"
                echo "Source-Commit: $(resources.pipeline.web-ci.sourceCommit)"
                echo "Version: $(resources.pipeline.web-ci.version)"
                echo "Version: $(resources.pipeline.web-ci.variables.version)"
                echo "environment: $(resources.pipeline.web-ci.parameters.environment)"
                echo "environment: $(resources.pipeline.web-ci.templateParameters.environment)"
```

In the above CD pipeline, am able to get the pipeline-Id & Source-Commit (i.e., predefined variables). But unable to fetch the user-defined variables and parameter values like version and parameter.

An early reply would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building on @Cloudziu's excellent work:

According to the Microsoft docs, PublishArtifacts is [deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/publish-build-artifacts?view=azure-devops), and MS recommends using the [`publish` task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/pipeline-artifacts?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) instead. An analogous `download` task exists, but for transferring information between stages or between pipelines, you must still use the [DownloadPipelineArtifacts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/download-pipeline-artifact?view=azure-devops) task.

If you have two pipelines, `pipeline-one` which triggers `pipeline-two` upon completion, you can pass info from one to the other like this:

To publish from pipeline-one:

```
- powershell: |
    $json = @"
    {
        'build_id': '$(Build.BuildID)',
        'build_number': '$(Build.BuildNumber)',
        'build_type': '$(Build.Reason)',
        'source_repo': '$(Build.Repository.Name)',
        'source_branch': '$(Build.SourceBranchName)',
        'source_commit_id': '$(Build.SourceVersion)'
    }
    "@
    $f = '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/s/ansible.json'
    Add-Content -Path $f -Value $json
  displayName: Create artifact from variables

- publish: ansible.json
  artifact: theAnsible
  displayName: Publish the artifact
```

To read the artifact in pipeline-two:

```
resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: pipeline1
    source: xyzzy.pipeline-one
    trigger:
      enabled: true
      branches:
        include:
        - develop
        - release_*
    
- task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
  displayName: Download the artifact
  inputs:
    source: 'specific'
    project: 'the-project-name'
    pipeline: 'xyzzy.pipeline-one' # this works
    # pipeline: 12 # or use the pipeline number instead
    preferTriggeringPipeline: 'true'
    runVersion: 'latest'
    artifact: theAnsible
    path: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/s/'

- powershell: |
      $f = "$(Pipeline.Workspace)/s/ansible.json"
      if( Test-Path $f ) {
        Get-Content $f
      } else {
        Write-Host '$f not found'
      }
  displayName: Read the artifact
```

Answer (score 2):

For your case I would use **Pipeline Artifacts**. Full description you can find here https://tsuyoshiushio.medium.com/how-to-pass-variables-with-pipeline-trigger-in-azure-pipeline-5771c5f18f91

**In CI Pipeline**

Export all necessary variables to a textfile, next publish it as an Artifact.

```yaml
  - task: CmdLine@2
    displayName: Create artifact from variables
    inputs:
      script: |
        echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=FOO;]$(FOO)" >  $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/pipeline.env
  - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
    displayName: publish variables
    inputs:
      PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
      ArtifactName: 'variables'
      publishLocation: 'Container'
```

**In CD Pipeline**

Create a task, which will download the Artifact containing the variables.

```yaml
- task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@0
  displayName: 'Download variables'
  inputs:
    buildType: 'specific'
    project: '<YOUR_PROJECT_ID_HERE>'
    pipeline: '<YOUR_PIPELINE_ID_HERE>'
    buildVersionToDownload: 'latest'
    downloadType: 'specific'
    downloadPath: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)'
```

Comment: Hello Cloudziu, Appreciate your answer. It's working fine, if, we are using azure hosted pipelines. In my case, am using rolling strategy deployment (i.e environment.machine_name) which is not working fine

Comment: how to use this artifact after downloading it in CD?